# Python Web Services

Tags: python, web-services

Elementree has become the accepted standard for interacting with xml.  What is the prevalent web service/SOAP library in use today?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about an accepted standard, but I've found [SOAPpy](http://soapy.sourceforge.net/) to be fairly straight-forward and useful library for handling SOAP-based web services.

> SOAPy is a SOAP/XML Schema Library for Python. Given either a WSDL or SDL document, SOAPy discovers the published API for a web service and exposes it to Python applications as transparently as possible.

IBM provide a [good walk-through and example](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ws-pyth5/) on their site for getting started with SOAPpy.

SOAPpy's no longer under active development, but is instead being folded into Zolera SOAP Infrastructure (ZSI) at the [Python Web Services Project](http://pywebsvcs.sourceforge.net/). This project however has alos [not seen much activity](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywebsvcs) since November last year.

Comment: I've seen a lot of talk about SOAPpy but it doesn't appear to be an active project.  The SF page you linked only has a .1 from 2001.

Comment: It's not active anymore, but is still useful at the very least as an introduction to web services in Python. Edited the answer to (hopefully!) make project status a little clearer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

soaplib is very easy to use and seems to be active.

http://web.archive.org/web/20090729125144/https://wiki.github.com/jkp/soaplib/

Comment: That page is no longer available.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but for anyone else who is asking this question I've had good success with suds:
https://fedorahosted.org/suds/