# WebService client libraries for Python and Perl

Tags: python, perl, web-services

I want to access web service in Python or/and Perl scripts. What are the most popular and reliable libraries today?

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159802/python-web-services) question, and I know about SOAPpy and ZSI. Can anybody say something about this libraries? Are they reliable enough for use in production?

Comment: web service, such a broad concept , what exactly you are trying to achieve

Comment: I want to invoke methods on server using SOAP protocol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're talking about SOAP then for Python I would definitely recommend `suds` :
https://fedorahosted.org/suds/

Answer (score 0):

Checking couple of libraries for SOAP (including suds) only ZSI worked reliably for me. It is not complicated to use and it just works(tm). I recommend that.

Answer (score 0):

Perl has fantastic CPAN libraries available for doing SOAP.  Probably the easiest would be [SOAP::Lite](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?SOAP::Lite):

> SOAP::Lite is a collection of Perl modules which provides a simple and lightweight interface to the Simple Object Access Protocol (SOAP) both on client and server side.

See more on the CPAN page.