# What is the best way to implement web services in Python?

Tags: python, web-services, rest, soap

What is the best way to implement web services in Python?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python Web Services](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159802/python-web-services)

Comment: I believe the question is about creating services, not clients.

Answer (score 1):

There are two main flavors of [web services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service):

- [RESTful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713847/recommendations-of-python-rest-web-services-framework)
- SOAP based ([old article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ws-pyth5/))

I suggest you look into the RESTful stuff first. IMO, it is generally simpler to produce and/or consume a RESTful service, than it is to use SOAP.