# Python Web Services

Tags: python, soap, service

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python Web Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159802/python-web-services)
>   [What's the best SOAP client library for Python, and where is the documentation for it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206154/whats-the-best-soap-client-library-for-python-and-where-is-the-documentation-fo)

What tool would you recommend to use with Python to consume Web Services?

I have thought about using SOAP.py, but some of the libraries it relies on (PyXML) are out of date. Plus, it seems as if it is not in active dev/support anymore.

FYI: I am consuming a SOAP web service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend [suds](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/). It is very simple and easy to use.

---

Simple example:

```
from suds.client import Client

url = 'http://localhost:7080/webservices/WebServiceTestBean?wsdl'
client = Client(url)
result = client.service.MyMethod(args)
```

For more examples / tutorial see their [documentation page](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/wiki/Documentation)..

Comment: Thank you. Could you point me in the direction of a possible tutorial?

Comment: I see. It doesn't seem like they have a package to install on windows?

Comment: You can download a tarball and install it as a python egg with `python setup.py install`